# Display Years as Text vs Numeric Values on Plotly Legend

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

When displaying a chart with an axis that represents Years, Plotly sees them as numeric values. If there are only a few of them, the legend for the x axis below displays as 2022, 2022.5, 2023, and 2023.5.

```
var traceA = {
    x: [2022,2023],
    y: [14610178,2598912],
    type: 'bar',
    marker: { color: '932BD4' }
};
```

The only solution I've found is to add non-numerals, such as x: `['(2022)','(2023)']` but it would be preferable to display just the numerals.

What am I missing in preventing them from being seen as numeric values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the years in x to be treated as date by setting the x axis [`type`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-type) accordingly, though you would have `Jul 2022` instead of `2022.5`, etc. so you would still need to specify [`dtick`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-dtick) to prevent showing intermediate values, for example :

```js
const data = [{
  x: [2022, 2023],
  y: [14610178, 2598912],
  type: 'bar',
  marker: { color: '932BD4' }
}];

const layout = {
  xaxis: {
    type: 'date',
    dtick: 'M12'
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

You could also just set `dtick=1` without changing the axis type. Or, you could set the axis type to `'category'`, in which case no need to set `dtick`.